# how to solve Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)?

Tags: python, web-scraping, jupyter-notebook

I have been trying to solve this error for a long time and have tried many methods given to solve it. Please help me with the same. The code and error are in the screenshot.

```
url = "https://www.moneycontrol.com/financials/adani%20ports/balance-
sheetVI/MPS"
response = requests.get(url, timeout=240)
response.status_code
content = response.json()
content.keys()
```

The traceback:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
JSONDecodeError                           Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-90-f7433ffb5f41> in <module>()
      1 url = "https://www.moneycontrol.com/financials/adani%20ports/balance-sheetVI/MPS"
      2 response = requests.get(url, timeout=240)
----> 3 content = response.json()
      4 content

3 frames
/usr/lib/python3.6/json/decoder.py in raw_decode(self, s, idx)
    355             obj, end = self.scan_once(s, idx)
    356         except StopIteration as err:
--> 357             raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
    358         return obj, end

JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

Comment: Print response.content; most likely the response is not json.

Comment: If you are expecting a json-like response, it's possibly JSON Lines. That's often the reason for the specific `line 1 column 1 (char 0)` location. You need to show at least a bit of the response

Comment: Scratch my last comment. That's a website, not some kind of programmed API. There is no reason to expect a JSON response

Comment: You are getting a full html retuned - you can display it in a browser:

Answer (score 0):

I think you should add some headers and determine that you accept json data.
try the code below:

```
url = "https://www.moneycontrol.com/financials/adani%20ports/balance-
sheetVI/MPS"    
headers = {'content-type': 'application/json'}
response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
```

Comment: Right, and did you test this?